# Reverse drawing order at the half of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, coverflow

I have the following `ViewPager`:

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to build a cover-flow-view. Which means that the position and the size of the views in the `ViewPager` change depending on touch input.

Everything works just fine with my implementation except for the drawing order of the views.

I can either call `pager.setPageTransformer(false,PageTransformer())` which looks like in the image above, or `setPageTransformer(true, PageTransformer())` which would reverse the drawing order.

The problem is, that i need the middle view(green) to be in front of its neighbours(blue,gray).

I read some posts about `view.bringToFront()` but I couldn't find a solution with that approach.
A middle-view-to-front-solution would be cool, but this would only work if there are three views visible at a time. With five views the fifth view would still overlap the fourth view. (confusing, isn't it?^^)

By the way, my minSdk is 16 to 18 so elevation(Lollipop) is not possible.

Here is my current `PageTransformer`

```
class PageTransformer() : ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    val MIN_SCALE = 0.75f

    override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
        val pageWidth = view.width
        val pageHeight = view.height
        var vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - MIN_SCALE) / 2
        var horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - MIN_SCALE) / 2
        view.scaleX = MIN_SCALE
        view.scaleY = MIN_SCALE
        if (position < -2) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.translationX = horzMargin - vertMargin / 2
        } else if (position <= 2) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            val scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position))
            vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2
            horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2
            if (position < 0) {
                view.translationX = horzMargin - vertMargin / 2
            } else {
                view.translationX = -horzMargin + vertMargin / 2
            }
            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            view.scaleX = scaleFactor
            view.scaleY = scaleFactor
            view.rotationY = position * -30
        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.translationX = -horzMargin + vertMargin / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Summing this up, I need a `ViewPager` which reverses its drawing order after the current Item.

Note: I have already tried every available library, but nothing worked.

I hope there is a genius who can help me :)

Comment: Can you a pencil sketch of whats your need? I don't quite understand it

Comment: the gray view overlaps the green one bevause drawing order is left to right. i want a middle-to-side order.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet.........

Answer (score 1):

you can overwrite the getChildDrawingOrder of the viewpager class:
Like so

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i) {
    int j = getCurrentItem ();
    if (i == j) {
        return childCount - 1;
    }

    if (i == childCount - 1) {
        return j;
    }

    if (j == 0) {
        if (i == 1) {
            i = 2;
        } else if (i == 2) {
            i = 1;
        }
    }

    return super.getChildDrawingOrder (childCount, i);
}
```